# How to put app in "What's new" section in Software Center

Tags: software-center, application-development

as the title says, I want to know how to put my new commercial app in "What's new" section in Software Center. I published it 2 weeks ago and I still can't see it in "What's new" section. So do I to do something to get my app on that section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is a bug or you did'nt noticed your app in what is new section, Apps submitted through my apps portal wiil be automatically included in what is new section